# How to display snackbar infinite duration in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

I created flutter project in android studio and tried to show snackbar infinite duration.This is my code

```
 final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text('Cart:'+countProducts.toString()+" Products($countCost:sum)",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft:Radius.circular(22),topRight:Radius.circular(22))),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
    action: SnackBarAction(
      textColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      label: "Buy",
      onPressed: () {
        // Some code to undo the change.
      },
    ),
  );

  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

There is another button that will change snackbar text. But I do not want to it dismiss back.So how to display snackbar infinite duration in flutter

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the Duration property on the snackbar

Example

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text('Cart:'+countProducts.toString()+" Products($countCost:sum)",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft:Radius.circular(22),topRight:Radius.circular(22))),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
    action: SnackBarAction(
      textColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      label: "Buy",
      onPressed: () {
        // Some code to undo the change.
      },
    ),
   duration: Duration(seconds: double.infinity),
```

//Gets problem int != double
      );

using `Duration(seconds: double.infinity)`

Not Sure if this is the best though.

### EDIT

You can try the following instead of using `double.infinity`

```
Duration(days: 365)
```

Reference

- [Duration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SnackBar/duration.html)

Comment: `seconds` parameter only accepts integers. using `double.infinity` will raise: 

The argument type `double` can't be assigned to the parameter type `int`